# Python: Replace Slashes

Tags: python, string

I got some unicode with percent signs I want to change to backslashes. I know you need an additional backslash as an escape sequence, but when I did this `replace()` gave me two backslashes:

```
>>> s ="%20%u200F%u05D1%u05E8%u05DB%u05EA%u200F%20%u200F%u05D4%u05E8%u05D9%u05D7%u200F%20%u200F%u05D5%u05D1%u05E8%u05DB%u05EA%u200F%20%u200F%u05D4%u05D5%u05D3%u05D0%u05D4"
>>> s.replace("%","\")
File "<stdin>", line 1
s.replace("%","\")                  
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

>>> s.replace("%","\\")
'\\20\\u200F\\u05D1\\u05E8\\u05DB\\u05EA\\u200F\\20\\u200F\\u05D4\\u05E8\\u05D9\\u05D7\\u200F\\20\\u200F\\u05D5\\u05D1\\u05E8\\u05DB\\u05EA\\u200F\\20\\u200F\\u05D4\\u05D5\\u05D3\\u05D0\\u05D4'
```

The `'r'` qualifyer isn't working either. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is just python invoking the string `__repr__` because you're in the REPL and the `__repr__` escapes the `\` character giving you the output you see.

Using `print`, which will use the strings `__str__`, will get you the right output:

```
print(s.replace("%","\\"))    
\20\u200F\u05D1\u05E8\u05DB\u05EA\u200F\20\u200F\u05D4\u05E8\u05D9\u05D7\u200F\20\u200F\u05D5\u05D1\u05E8\u05DB\u05EA\u200F\20\u200F\u05D4\u05D5\u05D3\u05D0\u05D4
```

That is, the replacement happens just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you have to type two backslashes to enter one, Python, when displaying a quoted string, displays two to indicate it is a literal backslash.  `'\\x41'` is four characters, `'\x41'` is one (equivalent to `'A'`).  It's a debugging feature so you can see unprintable characters, for example, and tell the difference.

```
>>> a = '\xa0\\xa0'
>>> a
'\xa0\\xa0'
>>> print(a)
 \xa0
```